# On solving heat equation from ancient time

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem asks to find all $C^2$ solution for
$$u_t-u_{xx}=t-x^2,\quad (t,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2$$
satisfying
$$\lim_{|x|+|t|\to \infty}\frac{|u(x,t)|}{|x|^5+|t|^5}=0$$

The typical heat equation with $(t,x)\in [0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and initial condition $u|_{t=0}=0$admits simple heat kernel $H(x,t)={1 \over \sqrt{4\pi t}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{4t})$ and solves the equation by simple setting $u=(t-x^2)*H(x,t)$. But it is not obvious to me that a direct heat kernel analogues from the above case can be deduced to the $(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ case. It also seems not that realistic to apply Fourier transform to the equation since in this case we are going to dealing with nontrivial distributional equation, so I am not sure where to start. Any comment shall be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you missing a condition at $x=0$?

Comment: @RonGordon There is not any initial or boundary conditions...

Comment: There is indeed an initial condition.

Comment: @RonGordon where is the initial condition?

Comment: "The typical heat equation with $(t,x)\in [0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and initial condition $u|_{t=0}=0$..."

Comment: @RonGordon That is not within the problem, it is just a comment on standard heat equation.

Comment: Have you found the solution? Would you please share it if you have?